# Duplicate entry '2' for key '1' using PK

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, primary-key

I'm using the primary key of userID to save items to a database which can then be viewed on the website in table form only by that logged in user.

I have the save working and the view items for that userID however when I try to save a second item I get the duplicate entry error. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the database or code, any advice on fixing this?

database:
userID
mediumint(6) 
null: No
default: None 
AUTO_INCREMENT

Code to Save:

```
function get_id($db,$username) 
{   
   $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users where username=?");
   $stm->execute(array($username));
   return $stm->fetchColumn();
}

$userID = get_id($db,$_SESSION['username']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO saved (userID, title, desp
          VALUES ($userID, '$title', '$desp')";
```

Comment: Are you trying to save a second item with the same userID? If so, then you don't want userID to auto increment!

Comment: is there a way to do it without removing auto increment?

Comment: What is the structure of the "saved" table? Make sure userID is not set to unique.

Comment: userID should be unique in the "users" table, but not in the "saved" table if you want to add multiple records for the same user. It will be a foreign key in that case.

Comment: I have the userID set to unique in the users table and not in the saved table but still get the duplicate error.. going to keep looking

Answer (score 0):

I think your userID column is set to Primary Key or Unique Key and hence it should be unique. Might be you are trying to insert same value to it again which is not allowed.